# different height values for the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid;">
    <span style="height: auto;">
        lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
    </span>
    <a>... more</a>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){

        console.log( $('.container span').height() );   // = 205

        $('.container a').on('click', function(){
            $('.container span').css('height', 'auto');
            console.log( $('.container span').height() );  // = 168
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't understand why I get 2 different height values for the same element after jquery set height auto with css().

**EDIT**

I found the problem, it's from google fonts.. font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;

https://jsfiddle.net/h97zdf6q/2/

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300italic,300,400italic,600,600italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif; ">
    <span style="height: auto;">
        lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
    </span>
    <a>... more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have the problem on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/h97zdf6q/  Do you have more html around this div or span ?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any other code which you're not showing? Like you're changing the text, or margins, or padding, or something?

Comment: @SimonM. on jsfiddle works ok for me.. seems that the problem is on me

Comment: Sounds like OK, jsfiddle works form me too. Anyway, i suggest you to take a look in your CSS (if it's affecting the element by hierarchy or directly) and check your DOM handling (callbacks, triggers, load event...). Client-side can change it you know.

Comment: I found the problem, it's from google fonts.. font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;

https://jsfiddle.net/h97zdf6q/2/